# How to get random generated argument from a method in a test without ArgumentCapture?

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, assertj

I want to get the arguments passed to the method when it is called. Since it is randomly generated, it is difficult to do the Assert.

Example :

```
class Car{
public void closeCar(){
      Integer doorNumber = new Integer(RandomInt);
      closeService.closeDoor(doorNumber);
    }
}
```

How can i get the **doorNumber** which generated? If i capture the number with @ArgumentCaptor, i don't know how i can do the assert since i don't know what to except.

Comment: In addition of my answer, if you have to use an ArgmentCaptor to make a test, you may have a conception problem.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you cannot verify exactly a random value but you can verify his type (instance of Integer), its nullity or that the new Integer don't throw an exception (depends on which Integer's constructor you use).